# Ionic 2 , unable to create APK file

Tags: ionic2

I have developed a sample ionic 2 application , and it is working fine locally in my windows system( browser ).

When I executed below command to create an .apk file , it is showing error depicted in the image.

```
ionic package build android
```

[image]

Any idea what needs to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: if "ionic serve" works without issue, try using "ionic build android" instead of "ionic package build android"

Comment: @AishApp will this work only if my system has android sdk ?

Comment: yes of course you need android sdk installed in your system. Also you have to include android platform to your ionic project